# iphone cocos2d CCSequence of Action and CCParticleSystem animation

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, core-animation

I´m new to Cocos2d. I´m trying to run two animations one after another. 
The first one is:

```
CCAction *walkAction;
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation 
                         animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.15f];
bear = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"normal1.png"];        
walkAction =   [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
[bear runAction:walkAction];
[spriteSheet addChild:bear];
```

The second which I want to fire right after the first one is:

```
     CCParticleSystem *killPigAnim = [CCParticleSystemPoint particleWithFile:@"killPigAnim.plist"];
     [self addChild:killPigAnim];
```

How can I achive that when the second one is not an action but the CCParticleSystem object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the action `CCCallFunc` to either call the start method on the particle system or call a method in your class which starts the particle system.

i.e.

```
-(void) startParticles
{
    //Start your particles
}


-(void) myOtherMethod
{
    ...
    walkAction =   [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
    CCCallFunc *callAction = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startParticles)];
    [bear runAction:[CCSequence actionWithActions:walkAction, callAction, nil];
    ...
}
```